# How to load external css in CakePHP?

Tags: jquery, css, cakephp

I'm trying to include an external css in a CakePHP view but it seems to be not working.
I'm using CakePHP 2.5.3

In a view index.ctp, I added the following code:

```
<?= $this->Html->css('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css', false); ?>
<?= $this->Html->script('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js', false); ?>
```

The jquery UI javascript is correctly loaded but the css does not appear in the generated HTML page. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me as in the `<link>` element is being generated, however since you are using the options wrong it is being echoed directly.

Please check back on the docs, `HtmlHelper::css()` doesn't support passing a boolean as the 2nd argument, it has to be an array, and what you are actually looking for is the `inline` option.

- **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::css**
- **http://api.cakephp.org/2.5/class-HtmlHelper.html#_css**

```
<?php
$this->Html->css(
    'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css',
    array(
        'inline' => false
    )
);
?>
```